# SQL - Delete all duplicates but the highest of each group for each user ID

Tags: sql, select, group-by

It looks like we might have some duplicate values in our preference table ***so I want to delete all the duplicate entries for each user but the more recent one***. I've spent quite a while trying to come up with a solution and I just keep running around in circles. I've tried max, grouped by, sub-queries, etc. It's pretty easy to delete the highest, but not everything but the highest. And especially for each user

So in the database I might have:

```
id  :   name:       value   :   userId
1   :   sortOrder:  Asc     :   1
2   :   sortOrder:  Desc    :   1
3   :   sortOrder:  Asc     :   2
4   :   something:  value2  :   1
```

*So in this case, I want to remove the first row since it's duplicate for User 1 and has the highest id and keep all the rest of the columns.*

So I know it's at least a sub-query with group by, but I just can't figure it out. So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id),
    name
FROM 
    preference
GROUP BY
    name
```

*which gives me a list of those I want to keep, **BUT** it still misses for each user*. So I somewhat want the opposite if I had it for each user. However I don't believe I can use <> in a sub-query anyways.

***What I want to ultimately do is say delete all those that have a lower ID for the same User that are duplicate entries.***

Comment: GROUP BY userID also if you want it per user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way, assuming `Id` column is a unique Id:

```
DELETE FROM preference
where Id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM preference GROUP BY name, userId)
```

[Note: The usual advice applies.  **don't** run in production without testing first]

Test First with:

```
SELECT * FROM preference
where Id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM preference GROUP BY name, userId)
```

SQLFiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/100e8/1). Works as intended. I suggest testing with a bigger data set though...

Comment: Running a delete without first playing around with a select is just asking for trouble ;)

Comment: which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: That's what I was missing the NOT IN and the second grouping. Didn't know you could do the second grouping in the same select. Thank you :)